# Base table or view not found:

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the error, try to fix it all the way but not wok for me if anyone knows please let me know.

[image]

Comment: show the migration file that you are trying to run.

Comment: Pls check config connect DB in `config/database.php`

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory. I'm assuming you're posting a question because you're absolutely certain that that table exists? If so can you provide some more details so we can also reproduce the problem?

Comment: @RyanNghiem I've checked the database file is fine. I'm getting is 'app_lv.locations' I don't know why it's occurs.

Comment: @SaurabhUpadhyay there is no wizard on StackOverflow who can predict what is going on in your code, unless you share some code. However since you don't like to share I will just say that you are trying to reference a table in one migration which is not created yet, meaning you have another migration that creates the `locations` table, but you try to use the `locations` table in a migration before that one runs. 
If you want more help, share some code!

Comment: I'm so sorry actually the main issue is when I was going to update the composer getting the below error. I thing so that's the issue if anyone knows what the exact code then please let me know https://prnt.sc/ny94tv

Comment: just see the full error in the laravel.log file you will find the exact answer where and why this query happens.

Comment: finally I got one error  Class 'Wildplay\NovaMoneyField\FieldServiceProvider' not found how can i resolved this

Comment: @SaurabhUpadhyay please update your question with your actual error

Comment: bro this is Actual error

Answer (score 0):

You may have in a Service Provider, some code that will look into `locations` table. This code will run before the actual artisan command, so it may be possible that you are looking at a table that is not yet created.

Try to disable all the app providers is `config/app.php` and see if the migration works. Then, if that's the case, refactor your code so that it won't happen again on a new machine.

Comment: No, you are getting a different error. But we can't help you because we don't have much knowledge about your code. 

Search in your project where you access `locations` table or that ServiceProvider and debug from there.